# Sides of a triangle are in Arithmetic Progression, then find $\tan (\alpha+ \frac{\beta}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

The sides of a triangle are in Arithmetic Progression. If the smallest angle of the triangle is $\alpha$ and largest angle of the triangle exceeds the smallest angle by $\beta$, then find the value of $\tan (\alpha+ \frac{\beta}{2})$

Would it be correct to assume sides of triangle of as $1,2,3$ and then apply cosine rule to find angles? Or could someone propose a better approach?

Comment: Is the answer a definite number, for any value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$? I am asking this because that doesn't seem to be the case. For example, for triangle with sides (3,4,5), the answer is approximately "2" and for triangle with sides (3,5,7), it will be approximately 2.89. Do you need the answer in terms of a particular variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

I don't think you can assume the sides of the triangle are $1,2,3$.  You can assume that they're $x, x+c,$ and $x+2c$, though.

If the smallest and largest angles are $\alpha$ and $\alpha + \beta$, then you know the middle angle is $\pi - 2 \alpha - \beta$.

Then from Law of Sines you know that

$$\frac{x}{\sin \alpha} = \frac{x+c}{\sin (2\alpha + \beta)} = \frac{x+2c}{\sin (\alpha+\beta)}.$$

(I used the fact that $\sin(\pi - \theta) = \sin(\theta)$.)

Now, $(2 \alpha + \beta) = 2(\alpha + \frac{\beta}{2})$, so using a half-angle formula along the way could get you somewhere.

Can you take it from here?